# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. getting this error in react from virtual host url

Tags: php, reactjs, cors, preflight

I am getting this error while hitting an auth api from react js using axois. here are my virtual host details    <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName salesforce-api.local
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/project1/htdocs/api/public/"

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/project1/htdocs/api/public/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all  

</Directory>
```

and here is my react api call..

```
const headers = {
            'Accept':'*/*',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
          };

        axios.post(apiUrl,requestData,{headers})
        .then(response => {
            setData(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        });
```

I am trying to fulfill CORS policy.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I included following headers in my root file.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, 
OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request- 
Headers, Authorization");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request- 
Headers, Authorization");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
die();
```

Comment: FYI, listing `Origin` and `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header is never necessary; you can safely drop those three names. Also, not sure what `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` is supposed to accomplish...